# How do I use Laravel Query Global Scopes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, global-scope

I am implementing Laravel Global Scope as documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes) but this seems to be not working for me. Below is my line of code in `User.php` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booted" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('age', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('age', '>' , 100);
        });
    }
}
```

and when I fired `User::all()` it only gives me user query as `select * from users`

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong or missing something here...

Comment: is `User` referring to `App\User` where you are using `User::all()`?

Comment: Yes. The Eloquent returns data but does not add that where condition

Comment: Are you by any chance using Tinker? If you are, and you've saved the file (`User.php`) after opening a Tinker session, you need to exit it first and start it again. By Tinker I mean `php artisan tinker`.

Comment: You have to call `parent::boot()` at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @AmirAsyraf Nope I have not used any Tinker. It is just normal route controller call

Comment: @Michael I tried that as well even though it was not mentioned in the Laravel Docs.

Comment: Try with `php artisan optimize` and/or `composer du`.

Comment: @Tpojka Still it is not working

Comment: Make `tests` table and `Test` model to try with new entity for sake of check does it work that way.

Comment: @Tpojka Nope I tried on another model and did `Post::all()` but still it gave `select * from posts`

Comment: Have you tried local scope if works (just for sake of it)?

Comment: Yes it does work but then I have to apply it for every query and I dont want that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218101/discussion-between-tpojka-and-abhi-burk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found what mistake I was making. If someone does the same please check the below details.

As mentioned in the question I am using Laravel 6.x but I was refering Laravel 7.x which has very much difference.
In Laravel 6.x we use

```
protected static function boot(){
   parent::boot();
   static::addGlobalScope(new BlockedUserScope);
}
```

and in Laravel 7.x we use

```
protected static function booted(){
   static::addGlobalScope(new BlockedUserScope);
}
```

Comment: Yeah and I was trying the latest one on Laravel 6.x

Comment: Why? Where is it documented? I've been struggling to find the right way how to do this in L8. Boot or booted?

Comment: L 6.x has `boot` - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#global-scopes and L 7.x or > has `booted` - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Answer (score 2):

in Laravel 8.x we use

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->join('model_has_roles', function ($join) {
                $join->on('model_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->where('model_type', '=', 'App\Models\User');
            })
            ->join('roles', function ($join) {
                $join->on('role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
                    ->where('roles.name', '=', 'visitor');
            })
            ->select('users.*');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8's `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`,
I can see 3 calls, wihtout anything in between, like:

```php
static::booting();
static::boot();
static::booted();
```

Meaning placing our logic at end of `boot()` method is same for all versions.

Hence, no matter what Laravel version, try something like:

```php
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new BlockedUserScope);
}
```